# how to call TextView in Other method MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to solve this error when i want to call TextView in other method its show error  Please help me this
This is MainActivity Class i want show message from this method

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private final Context mContext = this;
private SignalRService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;
private TextView lblmessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lblmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlbl);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

     public void showm(String v)
        {
            TextView  lblmessage2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlbl2);
           lblmessage2.setText("Customer: "+ v);

        }

}
```

Error

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simplesignalrclient, PID: 31222
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)'
    on a null object reference
    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java: 2093)
    at com.example.simplesignalrclient.MainActivity.showm(MainActivity.java: 91)
    at com.example.simplesignalrclient.MainActivity.showmessage(MainActivity.java: 87)
    at com.example.simplesignalrclient.SignalRService$1$1.run(SignalRService.java: 128)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 759)
```

Comment: You may paste all Activity code please.Where is you "onCreate" method?

Comment: From where do you want to call this? From the Activity in which textview is there or from Other Activity

Comment: i am calling this showm this method from other class

Comment: If you need from another activity, you should send the current activity from parameter and them, find again the textview and use it

Comment: other class not a activity class only process data and show some text i want show text my main activity

Comment: Pass the TextView as a param to the other class and then use it

Comment: i am new in android help show some example

Comment: This probleme have been solved at this links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind

Comment: could you please add the code that calls `public void showm(String v)` too?

Answer (score -1):

For the Main Activity when calling the Method-

```
yourClass.showm(v,lblmessage2);
```

And in the class

```
 public void showm(String v,TextView lblmessage2)
    {

       lblmessage2.setText("Customer: "+ v);

    }
```