# java.lang.NullPointerException on making my app

Tags: java, android

the app crashes and dont even open and give the error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

```
package com.example.andriod.hostelapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


    EditText userId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    public void login()
    {
        if (userId.getText().toString().equals("ritwik7101") && 
            userPassword.getText().toString().equals("ritwik123"))

        {
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "INCORRECT USERNAME OR PASSWORD!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: when i enter only this line and nothing else the app dont open                                                                       
           EditText userId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `findViewById` calls inside the `onCreate` method and after the `setContent` call.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are instantiated (invocation of the `find..` method) at the time when your class is instantiated, so before the layout is set. Because of this, the elements you want to find are not existing yet.

Here is the same question, including an answer to it: [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind)