# Speech-To-Text App Error

Tags: android-studio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I cannot make a simple Speech-To-Text app work (I'm new to Java). I have been working on this code for several days and refuses to launch due to these errors:

```
    08-13 12:35:08.784 26041-26041/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blindnavi.navirecog2, PID: 26041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blindnavi.navirecog2/com.blindnavi.navirecog2.NaviVoice}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.blindnavi.navirecog2.NaviVoice.<init>(NaviVoice.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 

I do not know what most of these errors mean so i cannot fix the program myself. Please leave your suggestions below!

Your help is appreciated!
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in another stackoverflow question [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind)

An Activity is not fully initialized and ready to look up views until after setContentView(...) is called in onCreate().

So only declare the fields uninitialized and then assign the values in onCreate: