# Android app stops when trying to change activity

Tags: android

In my app, there is a registration button which is supposed to open an activity named "registrationActivity"
I tried this:

In XML file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:onClick="startRegister"
/>
```

In Java file:

```
public void startRegister(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

but every time I click the register button, the app keeps stopping.

Edit 1: error from logcat:

> Runtime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                 Process: com.test.stork, PID: 5152
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test.stork/com.test.stork.RegistrationActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference

Edit 2:
I found the problem in the registrationActivity itself and now it works. Thanks so much everyone.

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat.  It will tell you why you're crashing.  Which is more likely to be in the new activity than the old one.

Comment: Is the `RegistrationActivity` mentioned in the Manifest ?

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace

Comment: yes, it's declared in manifest
 <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"</activity>
but still not working

Comment: Edit your question to include the full Activity, your layout and manifest. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind)

Answer (score 0):

Like Bruno mentioned in the comments, you need to declare the `RegistrationActivity` in your manifest file like :

```
<activity
    android:name="yourPackage.RegistrationActivity"/>
```

under the `application` object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your Registration Activity onCreate or onResume method.
Post your Registration xml. Basically it is failing to do something with a null object in your startup. Set a break point in your onCreate of your RegisterActivity and see which item is null and you will be good.