# User input in edit text field in android studio by manual typing and clicking buttons as well

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to take input from user in edit text field in android studio by manual typing by the user and clicking buttons as well. But some sorted out method on this site regarding this challenge is not working for me and throwing an exception (Attempt to invoke virtual method **'android.view.Window$Callbackandroid.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference)**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int quantity = getQuantity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
    // Increment button
    public void increment(View view){
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        while (quantity > 10){
            quantity = quantity - 1;
        }
        setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    // Decrement button
    public void decrement(View view){
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        while (quantity < 1){
            quantity = quantity + 1;
        }
        setQuantity(quantity);    
    }

    private int getQuantity(){
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.qty_edit_text);
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        return quantity;
    }

    private void setQuantity(int number){
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.qty_edit_text);
        editText.setText("" + number);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666091/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-windowcallback-android-view-wind)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getQuantity()` function before `setContentView(int res)` is called.
First of all don't initialize your EditText in `getQuantity()` and `setQuantity(int)`
Create EditText editText variable in `Main2Activity` class, but outside `onCreate(Bundle)` method. Just like you create `int quantity`.
It should looks like this:

```
int quantity = 0;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.qty_edit_text);
    quantity = getQuantity();
}
```

This way you can acces your `editText` from every method in `Main2Activity` class

Comment: Your method saved the app from crashing but manually typed value isn't getting assigned to quantity variable. Only button pressed value is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use button.setOnClickListener()instead of public void increment or decrement.make edit text global and on onCreate() method, set resource id for edit text.

Comment: Please elaborate the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the elaborated version. LOL

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
int quantity;
EditText editText;
Button IncrementButton, DecrementButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    quantity = getQuantity();
    editText = findViewById(R.id.qty_edit_text);
    IncrementButton = //findViewByid....
    DecrementButton = //FindViewByID

   IncrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           quantity = quantity + 1;
    while (quantity > 10){
        quantity = quantity - 1;
    }
    setQuantity(quantity);
        }
    });
  DecrementButton.etOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantity = quantity - 1;
           while (quantity < 1){
          quantity = quantity + 1;
    }
        setQuantity(quantity);    
          }

 }




private int getQuantity(){
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    return quantity;
}

private void setQuantity(int number){
    editText.setText("" + number);
}

}
```